# Drupal attach custom javascript library to entity print output

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to load an easy Javascript for the [Entity Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print) module. It should load a library defined in my theme, and a JS File.

I tried some hooks, (`_page`, `_preprocess_html`, etc) but had no chance to load the libraries for `entity-print.html.twig`. Also using `{{ attach_library('module/library') }}` didn't worked for entity print.

The only thing that worked for now was to use `hook_theme` to add a variable to render a variable, similar to the one used for css "entity_print_css".

Is there a way to load a library in a variable, or any way to load a library in entity print?

Comment: You need to use `use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;` to attach library manually in MODULE.module file. Or find some work around using twig filters.